# XPath / XQuery : How to retrieve all the array instead the first element when using

Tags: java, xml, xpath, apache-camel, xquery

I want to extract some info from an XML document like following:

```
<howto>
  <element>One</element>
  <element>Two</element>
  <element>Three</element>
<howto>
```

And I want, using xpah or xquery, to extract in one step the three elements, not just the fist one that I get when I query using `xpath("//element")`

Is there any way to do that in Java, preferably using xpath or xquery inside a Camel route?

Comment: Please try the very same in XQuery - and you will see that `//element` works there.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//element");
NodeList list= (NodeList) expr.evaluate(yourDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: That should work, but I want to have an ArrayList or String[] in one step, so I can avoid iterating the NodeList

Comment: @victor.hernandez in XPath 1.0 the only multi-valued return type is NODESET. If you set the return type to STRING then you will get just the value of the first element - that's the rule in XPath 1.0, to convert a node set to a string you take the value of its first node in document order. If you want to return a sequence of strings then you need to switch to an XPath 2.0 implementation such as Saxon 9's native s9api.